# I can not guess what happen in this two scenarios regarding Shift left?

Tags: arithmetic-expressions, bit-shift

Following two questions regarding the Shift Left is confusing me.

1. How many times would a suitable **binary number** be multiplied by if a Shift Left operation is performed on it five times?
   Answer is 32.
2. How many times would a suitable **number** be
   multiplied by if a Shift Left operation is performed on
   it five times?
   Answer is 16

Can some one please explain??

Comment: Am I reading it wrong or is it the same question with different answers?

Comment: Number and Binary number is the deference here.

Comment: But it's binary shift operatio in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 32.

For example 2 (binary 10) shifted 5 times is 1000000 which is 64.

Comment: Are you saying that the answer is 32 not 16?

Comment: I may be thinking wrong but shift operation applies to binary representation of a number.

Comment: First answer is 32 it doesn't matter. 16 is the one which confusing me.

Comment: Mmm.. don't know but should be correct most probably because it is from one of university test papers

Comment: Hmm. Leave your question open, maybe someone will have a good explanation.